# Weighted Overlay - passing parameter as text error?

Tags: arcpy, geoprocessing, spatial-analyst, parameters, error-999999

For some reason when hardcoding the save path for the wieghted raster just before runtime it works perfectly.  Like such...

```
arcpy.env.cellSize = "90"
arcpy.env.workspace = r'G:\Xcel\Route Tool\Potter\Scratch.gdb'
landuseRaster = r'G:\Xcel\Route Tool\Potter\Data.gdb\Potter_Randall_Landuse_Raster'
slope_Reclass_Raster = r'G:\Xcel\Route Tool\Potter\Scratch.gdb\slope_Reclass'

#Generate a list identifying what the individual input values should be reclassified as.
remapLanduse = RemapValue([['Cropland and pasture',2],['Herbaceous Rangeland',1],['Nonforested wetland',10],['Other agricultural land',1],['Strip mines, quarries and gravel pits',2],
                            [ 'Mixed rangeland',1],['Lakes',10],['Residential',3],['Commercial and Services',3],['Confined feeding operations',3],['Transportation, communications and services',10],
                            ['Transitional areas',3],['Shrub-brushland rangeland',1],['Other urban or built-up land',3],['Bare exposed rock',3],['Industrial',2],['Reservoirs',10],['Forested wetland',10],['Mixed urban or built-up land',3]])

remapSlope = RemapValue([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5],[6,6],[7,7],[8,8],[9,9],[10,10]])


#Define the input rasters, the field identifying the input values, the remap of their values, the weight of each raster, and the evaluation scale to use in the Weighted Overlay tool.
myWOTable = WOTable([[landuseRaster, 80, "LANDUSE", remapLanduse],
                     [slope_Reclass_Raster, 20, "Value", remapSlope],
                     ], [1, 10, 1])

outWeightedOverlay = WeightedOverlay(myWOTable)

arcpy.AddMessage("Creating weighted raster...")
weighted_Raster = env.workspace + '\\weighted_Raster'
outWeightedOverlay.save(weighted_Raster)
```

However when I try to pass the workspace to weighted overlay tool using parameter as text I receive a generic 999999 error? Like such....

```
subs  = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
originValue = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
destValue   = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
lines = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
Dem = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)
landuseRaster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6)
outwork = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(7)

arcpy.env.workspace = outwork + "\\Scratch.gdb"
```

.... run a few tools including generate 'slope_Reclass_Raster'

```
#Generate a list identifying what the individual input values should be reclassified as.
remapLanduse = RemapValue([['Cropland and pasture',2],['Herbaceous Rangeland',1],['Nonforested wetland',10],['Other agricultural land',1],['Strip mines, quarries and gravel pits',2],
                            [ 'Mixed rangeland',1],['Lakes',10],['Residential',3],['Commercial and Services',3],['Confined feeding operations',3],['Transportation, communications and services',10],
                            ['Transitional areas',3],['Shrub-brushland rangeland',1],['Other urban or built-up land',3],['Bare exposed rock',3],['Industrial',2],['Reservoirs',10],['Forested wetland',10],['Mixed urban or built-up land',3]])

remapSlope = RemapValue([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5],[6,6],[7,7],[8,8],[9,9],[10,10]])


#Define the input rasters, the field identifying the input values, the remap of their values, the weight of each raster, and the evaluation scale to use in the Weighted Overlay tool.
myWOTable = WOTable([[landuseRaster, 80, "LANDUSE", remapLanduse],
                     [slope_Reclass_Raster, 20, "Value", remapSlope],
                     ], [1, 10, 1])

outWeightedOverlay = WeightedOverlay(myWOTable)

arcpy.AddMessage("Creating weighted raster...")
weighted_Raster = env.workspace + '\\weighted_Raster'
outWeightedOverlay.save(weighted_Raster)
```

Comment: You might want to review Python's syntax for [string literals](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/strings.html), with special attention to escape sequences, because this code does not seem to use the `r` prefix consistently.

Comment: You are correct about the escape characters.   I have corrected and it still runs success (above) fail (below)? I think there is something else at play here?

Comment: In your debugging attempts, did you print out the values of the parameters such as `outwork` to verify they are what you expect? Sometimes the problem is as simple and basic as having a terminal "\\" in the path, resulting in two consecutive backslashes when the path is concatenated to the file name.

Comment: @whuber I am trying not to share entire code online... Is there a method I can pass along to you? (email or otherwise) I really think it's nothing with the syntax but rather with the tool?

Comment: You can quickly do a binary search to find a place in your code where the failure is occurring: that's all you need to post here. It really helps to post reproducible code if possible.

Comment: I am not sure what a binary search is?  I am using pyscripter IDE?

Comment: I'm assuming that the error refers to one of the getparameterastext lines. You could also try http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000038000000. It's possible you can't convert a raster object to a path, but I don't know what type of object your tool is trying to give the code. Edit: just noticed that you don't need to set the path to the weighted raster. You have already set the workspace. Just give outWeightedOverlay.save("weighted_Raster") the name as the string and it will save in the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who chimed in.  All very knowledgeable advice.  It was indeed an object issue with the slope_Reclass_Raster.  Corrected the variable with the following before passing to WOTable.

```
arcpy.AddMessage("Computing slope Reclass...")
outSlice = Slice('slope_Raster', 10, "NATURAL_BREAKS")
slope_Reclass_Raster = outSlice.save('slope_Reclass')
slope_Reclass_Raster = "slope_Reclass"
```